# How do I get the real filesystem path from within RingoJS webapp?

Tags: java, servlets, ringojs

If I manage to get ServletContext object from java's HttpRequest, I'd manage to accomplish this, but I couldn't find out how to access these objects from Ringo wrappers.

This is needed to create a file inside the webapp with some saved information. The relative paths correspond to different absolute paths in different enviroment, so we need to find the webapp absolute filesystem path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use `module.resolve()` to get the directory the current **module** is in. I assume you could just append the module name afterwards, like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = fs.join(module.resolve(), 'module-name.js');
```

I'm trying to find out a better way - no one on the IRC seems to respond, but I'll update this answer if I succeed.

**EDIT #1**: I can't seem to find a simpler way, and [it doesn't look like Rhino or ECMAScript 5 supports this natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049205/getting-the-path-of-a-script-in-rhino).